# I update my app to androidx and it's giving this error when I am trying to open my app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, androidx

I build app and update it to androidx and it's successfully installed in mobile also but after click the button application automatically stopped. but it's not showing any error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fast.android.phone.booster/fast.cleaner.battery.saver.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fast.android.phone.booster-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.fast.android.phone.booster-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2494)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.setContentView(ComponentActivity.java:380)
    at fast.cleaner.battery.saver.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not migrated your project fully to androidx.
Example: Where you have  in a non-androidx project as a tag opener for textview in XML, in androidx,                     <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView> it works like this.

For your specific problem, you need to change your tag openings to androidx or material as well.

Solution: is <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout> rather than just your normal non-androidx tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check all components form your activities and java imports after androidx import and rename every wrong code.
Like:`import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;` to `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;`.
This is just an example. If you think this answer is helpful you can check that tick button! Good luck!